# Rails activerecord inner join a custom object

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have classes:

```
class Want < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cached_buy_offers, dependent: :destroy
end
class CachedBuyOffer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :want
end
```

So, I can do

```
Want.joins(:cached_buy_offers)
```

which works as expected.
I want to generate following sql:

```
select * from wants
inner join 
(select cached_buy_offers.want_id, max(buy_offer_cents) as max_buy_offer,           count(cached_buy_offers.want_id) as buy_offer_count
from cached_buy_offers
where cached_buy_offers.want_id in (1,2,3,4)
group by cached_buy_offers.want_id
order by max_buy_offer) as cached_buy_offers
on cached_buy_offers.want_id = wants.id
```

Inner sql query can be generated using:

```
ids = [1,2,3,4]

CachedBuyOffer.select('cached_buy_offers.want_id, max(buy_offer_cents) as max_buy_offer, count(cached_buy_offers.want_id) as buy_offer_count').where('cached_buy_offers.want_id in (?)',ids).group('cached_buy_offers.want_id').order('max_buy_offer')
```

But when I try to do this:

```
Want.joins(CachedBuyOffer.select ..... the above activerecord inner query)
```

throws an error `RuntimeError: unknown class: CachedBuyOffer`

How can I generate the required sql?

Comment: I was trying this in rails console and CachedBuyOffer is defined there as well. I am also able to execute the activerecord inner query independently

Comment: Then did you try, `Want.joins(:cached_by_offer).select(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Arel.sql`.

```
ids = [1,2,3,4]

cached_buy_offer_subquery = CachedBuyOffer
.select('cached_buy_offers.want_id, 
  max(buy_offer_cents) as max_buy_offer, 
  count(cached_buy_offers.want_id) as buy_offer_count')
.where('cached_buy_offers.want_id in (?)',ids)
.group('cached_buy_offers.want_id')
.order('max_buy_offer').to_sql

Want.joins("INNER JOIN (#{Arel.sql(cached_buy_offer_subquery)}) cached_buy_offers ON cached_buy_offers.want_id = wants.id")
```

Answer (score 0):

`.joins` takes an association key as an argument, such as `Want.joins(:cached_buy_offer)`. You can chain queries off of that!